# Semaphore with 3 elements

Tags: c, process, ipc, semaphore

I need to write a code which will be make a semaphore with 3 elements for 2 process. I don't want to use forks.

1 = reservation 1 element

2 = reservation 2 elements

3 = reservation 3 elements

A = releases 1 element

S = releases 2 elements

D = releases 3 elements

I do not know how to solve the problem with reservation elements collision. While I wrote something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
key_t key = ftok(".", 'a');
int semid = semget(key, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
struct sembuf lock[3] = { {0, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {2, -1, 0} };
struct sembuf unlock[3] = { {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, (2, 1, 0) };

char input;
semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1);
semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, 1);
semctl(semid, 2, SETVAL, 1);

while(true)
{
scanf(" %c", &input);

switch(input)
{
    case '1':
        semop(semid, lock, 1);
        printf("\nSemaphore Locked\n");
        break;

    case '2':
        semop(semid, lock, 2);
        printf("\n2 Semaphores Locked\n");
        break;

    case '3':
        semop(semid, lock, 3);
        printf("\n3 Semaphores Locked\n");
        break;

    case 'A':
        semop(semid, unlock, 1);
        printf("\nSemaphore Unlocked\n");
        break;

    case 'S':
        semop(semid, unlock, 2);
        printf("\n2 Semaphores Unlocked\n");
        break;

    case 'D':
        semop(semid, unlock, 3);
        printf("\n3 Semaphores Unlocked\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("\nERROR\n");
        break;
}

}

semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);
semctl(semid, 1, IPC_RMID);
semctl(semid, 2, IPC_RMID);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If done without fork, process will block on semop and will not be able to get to scanf to get further input. If semop with IPC_NOWAIT is used, this problem will not happen and it is possible to print return from semop.